# Jquery each class item and compare

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of Images with data Attributes like this:

```
<img class="overlay" data-filename="red" src="img1.png">
<img class="overlay" data-filename="yellow" src="img2.png">
<img data-filename="blue" src="img3.png">
```

Thus I have Buttons like this:

```
<button class="lbtn" style="background-Color:red">
<button class="lbtn" style="background-Color:yellow">
<button class="lbtn" style="background-Color:blue">
```

If I click on the button red the Images which do no contain the data-filename red shall have an opacity of 0.

so far I did this but it wont work:

```
$('.lbtn').click(function() {
 $(".overlay").each(function() {
     if($(this).data('filename') == $('.lbtn').attr('src') {
         $(this).css({ opacity: 0 });
     }
 });
```

});

Comment: your button don't have src

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  OP is using `src` in his code that's what i am pointing out.

Comment: You check the attribute src of your button `$('.lbtn').attr('src')` but there is no attribute src. Also, there is a missing `)` your if-Statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can add a `data` attribute to the `button` elements which matches the `data-filename` on the `img`. You can then use this to `filter()` them and show/hide the relevant ones, something like this:

```js
$('.lbtn').click(function() {
  var filter = $(this).data('filter');
  var $imgs = $('.container img').hide();
  $imgs.filter('[data-filename="' + filter + '"]').show();
});
```

```css
.red { background-color: #C00; }
.yellow { background-color: #CC0; }
.blue { background-color: #00C; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img class="overlay" data-filename="red" src="img1.png" title="red">
  <img class="overlay" data-filename="yellow" src="img2.png" title="yellow">
  <img data-filename="blue" src="img3.png" title="blue">
</div>

<button class="lbtn red" data-filter="red">Red</button>
<button class="lbtn yellow" data-filter="yellow">Yellow</button>
<button class="lbtn blue" data-filter="blue">Blue</button>
```

Comment: Yes, it's all dependant on the values of `data-filename` and `data-filter` matching. They can be any string you need.

Answer (score 3):

1. use attribute selector with :not selector

[attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute, with any value.

[:not selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

> Description: Selects all elements that do not match the given selector.

```js
$('.lbtn').click(function() {
  var color = $(this).attr('style').split(":")[1]
  console.log(color)

  $('img:not([data-filename=' + color + '])').css({
    opacity: 0
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="overlay" data-filename="red" src="img1.png">
<img class="overlay" data-filename="yellow" src="img2.png">
<img data-filename="blue" src="img3.png">


<button class="lbtn" style="background-Color:red">Click</button>
<button class="lbtn" style="background-Color:yellow">Click</button>
<button class="lbtn" style="background-Color:blue">Click</button>
```

Comment: Similar to your answer on the question about hacking around the `class` attribute earlier, this is very brittle. It'll work, but it's very easy to break if you forget about the rules you've placed on the UI. Adding an extra rule in to the `style` will stop this working - or even improving the code by putting the style rules in a class on the element instead. It's for this exact reason why tying the JS and UI together is a really bad idea.

Comment: I Need to do this correct `$('.overlay:not([data-filename=' + color + '])').css({
` since I only want Images with the class overlay to be hidden

Answer (score 0):

Would change your code a little:

```
$('.lbtn').click(function() {
 var self= $(this);
 $(".overlay").each(function() {
     if($(this).data('filename') == $(self).attr('src') {
         $(this).css({ opacity: 0 });
     }
 });
```

var self= $(this); //this is element, which fired event, and you need to remember id due to check. When you try to check $('.lbtn').attr('src') it takes all three buttons and doesn't works
AND buttons need to have attribute src as well!